# How can I rephrase 461570 to avoid opinion?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

My question (and answer) [How can I run Firefox on an FSDG distribution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461570) has been closed as "opinion based". I believe that the question is a technical one (how do I install program X on a distribution that doesn't include it) and that the solution is factual and unbiased (use tool Y or tool Z).

Some people have strong opinions on: free software, FSDG certification, Snap, Flatpak, Firefox and the organizations behind each of them. Is this why the question was closed? If so, I don't think closing the question is an appropriate action, as that would imply that mere mentions of these are off-topic, which surely isn't the policy?

I am open to feedback. How can I rephrase the question to avoid opinion?

---

Update: In the meantime I've updated the answer considerably to provide:

- even-handed examples for Snap and Flatpak
- suitable forums for finding out "which option is best for me" (which would be opinion-based)

Comment: The question has now been reopened.

Comment: For what it's worth, I see nothing opinion based there. Seems like a great Q&A, thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get further feedback, but the question was reopened.